# Oracle SELECT Query With Multiple Date Formats

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

I am attempting to select a date column that includes multiple date formats, including yyyymmdd and yyyy.

When running the query below, the following error occurs: ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
select to_date(date_table.date,'yyyy-mm-dd'))
from head_table
inner join date_table
on date_table.recordID = head_table.recordID
```

Can someone please provide assistance on how to select a data based column that contains two formats.

My expected output for 4 different records would be:

```
2017-12-12
2014
2011-04-15
2015
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: what is your data column type? use `to_char` instead

Comment: If your column  is a date or timestamp, it has no format. Assuming it is a string, you need to find all the possible formats used in this column to represent a date, and build a query according to these formats. Can you list all the different formats in which dates are stored in this column? Also, your expected output only makes sense if compared to the corresponding starting data, so please post the data that should give that output.

Comment: Changing from to_date to to_char yields the ORA-01481: invalid number format model error.

Comment: There are two formats of dates in this column, yyyymmdd and yyyy. My end results is to have the output display yyyy-mm-dd and yyyy.

Comment: The table_date.date is varchar2(23).

Comment: **Never** store date values in a `varchar` column. The problem you have right now is a direct result of that wrong design. You should change that column to a proper `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`)  column as soon as possible.